# react componentWillReceiveProps data replication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm getting some troubles on getting some data. At `componentWillReceiveProps` I must receive an object `widgets`, but I perceived that the object `widgets` contains another object `widgets` and I have to access it by `widgets.widgets`.

Expected value: `widgets: { value1: 10, value2: 20, value3: 30 }`

Actual value: `widgets: { widgets: { value1: 10, value2: 20, value3: 30 } }`

I know that its possible to do something like this (but I think that's ugly):

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ widgets }) {
  if (widgets !== this.props.widgets) {
    this.setState({ widgets: widgets.widgets });
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as widgetsActions from '../js/actions/widgetsActions';
import Dashboard from './dashboard/Dashboard';
import style from './App.scss';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      widgets: this.props.widgets,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.state.widgets) === JSON.stringify({})) {
      this.props.loadWidgets();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ widgets }) {
    if (widgets !== this.props.widgets) {
      this.setState({ widgets });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.app}>
        {(JSON.stringify(this.state.widgets) !== JSON.stringify({})) &&
        <div>
          <Dashboard widgets={this.state.widgets} />
        </div>
        }
     </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  loadWidgets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  widgets: PropTypes.shape({
    value1: PropTypes.number,
    value2: PropTypes.number,
    value3: PropTypes.number,
  }).isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    widgets: state.widgets,
  }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    loadWidgets: () => dispatch(widgetsActions.loadWidgets()),
  }
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it's a problem with your reducer setup.  The [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) section of the Redux docs describes a couple reasons why this can happen, and it's usually a misunderstanding of how `combineReducers` and slice reducers work together to define state structure.

Comment: Yes, after reading this, I saw that the problem was the name setted at my reducer return function.  Thank you!